# Running complexity of the below function with reason

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am not able to find the running complexity of the below function as there are 3 things connected here 1: input size 2: i value 3: s value. 
please help me find running complexity with reasoning.

```
def function(n):
    i=s=1
    while s<n:
        i=i+1
        s=s+i
        print("*")
function(20)
```

Comment: What do you think the running complexity of this code is?

Comment: What's your best attempt so far?  What are the values of the variables after the loop has executed `m` times?

Comment: The value of s at the ith iteration is the sum of first i positive integers.if k is the total no of iterations taken by the program,

Comment: 1+2+3+...+K=k(K+1)/2 which must be less then n

Comment: so from here i am not able to go further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `O(sqrt(n))` algorithm.

```
The loop runs i times such that `1+2+..i<=n.`[maximum i] 
or
i*(i+1)/2<=n or i^2/2<=n or i<=sqrt(2n) 
~O(sqrt(n))
```